# Scrolling JComponent in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jviewport

Say, I have a big JComponent:

```
Dimension componentSize = new Dimension(5000,5000);
```

And a smaller JScrollPane:

```
Dimension scrollPaneSize = new Dimension(500,500);
```

I want to display part of my JComponent in JScrollPane, like on the picture below:

[image: JComponent inside JScrollPane]

White rectangle is my JScrollPane, which currently displays part of JComponent from **(x1,y1)** to **(x2,y2)**.

---

So, what have I tried:

I have created a new JComponent:

```
JComponent component = new JComponent(){
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // Here I draw a background
    } 
};
```

And placed it as a viewport view in JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

scrollPane.setViewportView(component);
```

Then I attached JScrollPane to a JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And I try to change visible area with:

```
scrollpane.getViewport().setBounds(x1,y1,500,500)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setBounds` is used to determine the location and size of a component within it's parent container.  This isn't what you want to do.  Unless you are using an absolute layout, you should never use this method.

Instead, try

```
component.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(x1, y1, 500, 500));
```

Instead...

Check out [`JComponent#scrollRectToVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Comment: Thank Kleopatra if you see her, she taught me this really nice and easy solution :D

Answer (score 2):

This code will always cause the viewport to scroll regardless of the size of the viewport.

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition( new Point(x1, y1) );
```